# Formula to check if an opportunity is closed won

Tags: workflow, formula, opportunity, standard-objects

I have an existing workflow formula that reads:

```
Date_of_Event__c  - CloseDate > 30
```

I would like to add a criteria that checks if the closed opportunity was marked 'Closed won' so that its not firing for all the closed lost opportunities.

Answer (score 5):

You can check against the `IsWon` field.

```
AND(IsWon, Date_of_Event__c - CloseDate > 30)
```

You could also check `IsClosed` if you want to be sure you only fire for Closed/Won records:

```
AND(IsClosed, IsWon, Date_of_Event__c - CloseDate > 30)
```